# How can I get a better understanding of web app development using C# & MVC3/4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

I've tried jumping from iOS development straight into web development but I am having a VERY difficult time.

First off, I DO have a very basic understanding of HTML, SQL, OO programming, MVC, PHP, etc.
I am also capable of creating a basic C# console application.

What I don't understand as at all (PLEASE bear with me) is *where the files go*. Where and how do I upload the files to a server? I don't even really have a full understanding of how the project runs locally... where is the C# held and how is the HTML dished out to the browser? How does the C# get executed? I've searched and searched for tutorials but they all seem to assume you have already done this type of stuff. Is it so easy that I'm over complicating it?

I need a tutorial that walks me through the **entire** process. Not just a piece of it. I want to create a web application, test it locally, AND upload it to a production server (that I have at home or that is hosted else where)

Comment: start doing something useful, something that *you* think is useful. There is no better way to learn new technology then coding it in some project that you interested in.

Comment: There is plenty of stuff out there which you can use to start developing web applications. To clarify about where the files go; the files are .DLL and ASPX/CSHTML for MVC files which are stored in folder on the web server and that folder is mapped to IIS virtual directory. C# is a language and it does not execute. The execution is done by the asp.net engine and CLR. To run project locally you can use CASSINI or IIS EXpress or IIS. Hope this gives some insight.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1) to start with MVC

Comment: Take one subject at a time and master it. Start with HTML then to CSS -> Javascript/Jquery -> SQL-> ASP.NET -> MVC.  Google and you will find lots of tutorial.

Comment: You may find the following link useful, although it's very technical.  It discusses the low-level workings of how asp.net works.  It's a bit old, and does not cover MVC, but knowing this will help you understand MVC because MVC is built on top of the same architecture.  http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp  After this, you might want to watch this video on MVC (again, it's old, but still relevant) http://vimeo.com/10373753

Answer (score 1):

To learn MVC try first steps from this site: http://www.asp.net/mvc
Atleast, most part of main mvc things are explained there. Materials are presented in video and text variants. Just install VisualStudio and make your first MVC application from the existing template.
For CSS/HTML will help this sites:
CSS => www.w3schools.com/css/
HTML => www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Would be better as a comment..

Comment: add comment (requires 50 reputation) :(

Comment: Believe me, it is not that hard to get 50 reputation on Stackoverflow `;)`

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.net refer below link.

http://www.asp.net/get-started

For c#:

http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson01

You can also refer other site like - codeproject.com

It contains a lot of basic article to get started.

And During the development phase if you stuck somewhere then we (stackoverflow community) are here to answer your question. :)

Best of luck.